# Can Talents be taken multiple times?

Tags: wfrp-2e

I was wondering if it's possible to take talents like *Savvy*, which modify your *starting profile*,  multiple times.

If it is, then does the Character accumulate the +5% bonus on the specific Characteristic?

#### Example

Marlon is a Character with Int score of 30.

Marlon takes *Savvy* on his 1st career, the *Student*, and modifies his Int score to 35 in his *starting profile*.

After completing his 1st career, Marlon enters the *Apprentice Wizard* career, which gives the possibility to choose *Savvy* Talent.

Is Marlon allowed to choose *Savvy* again, modifying his *starting* Int score to 40?

Comment: Ever heard of recursion?

Comment: I know what recursion is. In the rulebook it does not state anything about recursion/multiple choices of Talents. For Skills there are Masteries, so I asked.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Talents, no. Talents represent that special ability and complement skills and define your character.

The +5% to the starting profile is a significant add in context of how skills grow in game through career advancement.

They are not cumulative in career advancement. Unfortunately, this is not called out in the rules very well.

**Edit**

Mentioned was Skill Mastery in comments above, this is a good example of how Talents are not "mastered," but inherent to the career first encountered or later found. Hardy is a birth Talent as is Night Vision. Hardy might be said you have or don't have and as you enter a new career that provides Hardy again, does it make you "more hardy"? I don't think so.

More context can be found in specifics: A Bone Picker may pick Hardy at character inception over Resistance to Disease and advance to Camp Follower. The choices for the Camp Follower are Hardy or Suave. Having taken Hardy in her Basic Career, Suave is left as the only option. It also means that the character *may* take Suave in Camp Follower to exit (100 XP). This is optional, per the Rules as Written.

> Many Careers offer skill and talent *choices*.  The Agitator career, for example, gives you the *choice* of the Coolheaded or Street Fighting talents. To start with you MUST take one of the two, otherwise you cannot complete the career.
>
> However, before finishing your advance scheme, you may spend XP to gain these OPTIONAL skills and talents. As always, each skill or talent costs 100 XP. You don’t have to buy these skills and talents to finish the career, but you do have the *option*. As always, check with your GM before doing so.
>
> Core Rulebook (US English, 1st printing), p. 28

I'll stipulate the oversight in the rules is subject to abuse. My arguments against stacking might cite: Night Vision. Do you become better at Night Vision? No. I think that the unwritten expectation is that adds to starting characteristics to the profile are one (1) time only, as are bonuses to skill checks, e.g., Menacing. The bonuses do not stack.

I will also cite Strike-to-Stun, as early as 2008, where this question was asked as well: [Two rules questions](http://bit.ly/PtQo9V).

Because of the lack of clarity I would not be surprised to find others with a contrary opinion, but lack of definition should not be assumed as "wiggle room."

Comment: I perfectly agree with your opinion. A newcomer player raised the issue, and now I'm sure to be right.

Comment: Its depend of the talent, exemple if it's talent is gived by a mutation it could be cumulative example 3 or 4 arms.

Comment: "It also means that the character must take Sauve in Camp Follower to exit (100 XP)" Does he? I'm pretty sure the rules state that in the case of "or" you have to have one. So having Hardy means he has satisfied the requirements for Camp Follower.

Comment: @IanDrash, you are correct, however my wording may need some massaging. I think what I was trying to say if you see _Hardy or Suave_, and having already taken _Hardy_, *then* _Suave_ must be taken.

Comment: "Must" be taken? My interpretation was always "might be taken". You can leave out talents or skills if there is a choice and you already have one of the two. There is no real reason to do so (unless you are in a real hurry to get to the new career), but it is a possibility.

Comment: @IanDrash, you are correct, sir. Updating answer.